# SQL Server : SUBSTRING position - negative value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, substring

What is the meaning of providing negative values on `substring`?

What will be the output of the following code?

```
Declare @Strings VARCHAR(20)
Select @Strings ='Lakhan Pal Garg'
Select SUBSTRING(@Strings, -9, 16)
```

How the value  ***Lakhan*** got as answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From **[`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx):**

> start
>
> Is an integer or bigint expression that specifies where the returned characters start. **If start is less than 1, the returned
>   expression will begin at the first character that is specified in
>   expression. In this case, the number of characters that are returned
>   is the largest value of either the sum of start + length- 1 or 0.** If
>   start is greater than the number of characters in the value
>   expression, a zero-length expression is returned.
>
> length
>
> Is a positive integer or bigint expression that specifies how many characters of the expression will be returned. If length is negative,
>   an error is generated and the statement is terminated. If the sum of
>   start and length is greater than the number of characters in
>   expression, the whole value expression beginning at start is returned.

```
Declare @Strings VARCHAR(20)
Select @Strings ='Lakhan Pal Garg'
Select SUBSTRING(@Strings,-9,16)
```

Number of characters get from beginning **`MAX(-9 + 16 - 1, 0) = 6`**

So your query is the same as:

```
Select SUBSTRING(@Strings,1,6)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383120)**</kbd>

Output: `Lakhan`

Comment: You rocks.. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: now the only question that remains is, "why would anyone need it to behave this way?".

Comment: @mao47 Well, it depends. I am not an author of implementation of SUBSTR but I guess with negative index it behaves like `LEFT(string, LEN(string) - 1 - index)`. It works the same way in PostgreSQL so maybe it is SQL standard.